# Python 3 type Dict with required and arbitrary keys

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to type a function that returns a dictionary with one required key, and some additional ones.

I've run into [TypedDict](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/), but it is too strict for my purpose. At the same time [Dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) is too lenient.

To give some examples with what I have in mind:

```py
class Schema(PartiallyTypedDict):
    name: str
    year: int

a: Schema = {"name": "a", "year": 1}  # OK
b: Schema = {"name": "a", "year": 1, rating: 5}  # OK, "rating" key can be added
c: Schema = {"year": 1, rating: 5}  # NOT OK, "name" is missing
```

It would be great if there was also a way of forcing values of all of the optional/arbitrary key to be of a specific type. For example `int` in example above due to "rating" being one.

Does there exist such a type, or is there a way of creating such a type in python typing framework?

Comment: I deleted my answer because totality only applies to keys explicitly declared. It won’t allow arbitrary extra keys. There is no type that allows you to declare such a dict.

Comment: At best you can use [type guards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647), new in 3.10